# how to install google earth on ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I'm attempting to load Google Earth on Ubuntu 16.04 and the package installer shows the following error:

```
 dependency is not satisfiable: lsb-core (>= 3.2)
```

I have read in various places that Google Earth can and can't be installed and that it depends on the lsb core and other lsb packages that are no longer supported . So as a noob to linux, I'm at a loss and confused.

How do I install Google Earth?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `lsb-core` is just fine, and is definitely stable enough for your needs.

All you really need to do is pop open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Then, let `apt` do its magic and install everything it needs to install. Google Earth will automatically be added to the install list, and will be configured.